# Laravel Blade engine does not work properly

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

i already uploaded my laravel 5.5 app on my host.

my problem is when i try to use

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

///

@endsection
```

in my views, HTML works fine but blade template doesn't work.

also when I check source code with the browser I find that the "@" mark doesn't exist.

my browser source code :

```
extends('layouts.app')
section('content')

///

endsection
```

Help me ! :)

Comment: Are your view files named with the `.blade.php` suffix?

Comment: @Cy Rossignol hi, yes they named with .blade.php.but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to work with Blade engine, make sure your view named with `.blade.php` extension just like [Cy Rossignol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5209322/cy-rossignol) mentioned in the comment. Example : `home.blade.php`. You can read [the docs here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade)